# System image arm eabi v7a of Android 4.4(API 20) is not noticed

Tags: sdk

I was trying to set up the environment to develop and debug a simple android app with the use of Android Virtual Device Manager. I had followed all the steps from google's website.
Moving to the next step, as I had selected the target to be 'Android 4.4W - API Level 20' details in the wizard 'create new android virtual device(AVD)', the CPU/ABI field was grayed out saying '**No system image installed for this target**'.

I had opened ANdroid SDK Manager to check if the mentioned target is holding a valid system image.

It had been updated with the latest packages from the respective repositories while contacting few of the repositories was a failure.

In the end, I had a surprise that my Android 4.4W (API 20) is not having its respective system image installed.

When I actually checked the folders that I had downloaded, I couldn't also notice the **System Images** sub folder under the SDK folder.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 4):

Start up Android SDK manager. Under "Android 4.4W (API20), make sure "sources for android sdk" is installed. If not, check the box and installed.

P.S. - I had the same problem.

Comment: Thank you Joel. It was because I could not download the necessary files that I have to install from their respective repositories. Got rid of this by changing the Proxy server address according to my machine under the Tools->Options of the SDK.

Comment: I do not see "sources for android sdk" under "Android 4.4W (API20)". How do I get this.

Comment: I don't see "sources for android sdk" under SDK manager, pls see my question here: stackoverflow.com/q/25813579/948268

Answer (score 2):

After installing the image you have to restart eclipse. Otherwise it can't see the image.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue. If you're running SDK Manager on Windows 7, run it with the admistrator privileges. That solved the problem in my case.

Comment: I am running as Adminstrator but still have this issue. Also I do not see "sources for android sdk" under "Android 4.4W (API20)". How do I get this.

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager -> Tools -> Options
Check Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://... 
You will see sources for android SDK, install it. 
Close SDK Manager and open it again, you wil see ARM EABI